# Routing IPv6-traffic from client via OpenVPN-server

Tags: openvpn, ipv6, gateway, tunnel

For playing and learning purpose i set up an OpenVPN-server. Im currently attached to a network without IPv6. Because of that, I would like to route all IPv6-traffic via the VPN. With IPv4 and iptables-Masquerading this already works perfectly well.

Now to IPv6: I set up IPv6 inside the network. Im able to establish connections and pings (ping6) between the client and the server inside the network.

The forwarding of the kernel of the server is activated.
The server has IPv6 connectivity to the outside.

I tried this setting:

```
push "route-ipv6 2000::/3"
```

and

```
push "route-ipv6 <my IPv6>"
```

If I want to ping some address on the "outside":

```
ping6 ipv6.google.com
connect: Network is unreachable
```

Even, if I set the correct interface with "-I tun2". (Just to make sure its not trying to use some other interface)

Now my configs and settings:

IP of the client:

```
inet6 addr: fdee:dead:b0b::1000/64
```

IP of the server:

```
inet6 addr: fdee:dead:b0b::1/64
```

The servers config:

```
port 443
proto udp
proto udp6
dev tun
tun-ipv6
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key
dh dh4096.pem
auth SHA512
server 10.0.0.0 255.255.255.0
server-ipv6 fdee:dead:b0b::/64
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
push "dhcp-option DNS 10.0.0.1"
client-to-client
keepalive 10 60
tls-auth ta.key 0
cipher AES-256-CBC
comp-lzo
max-clients 3
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
log-append  openvpn.log
verb 4
nice -19
```

Thats my kernel settings regarding the forwarding:

```
net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding = 1
net.ipv4.conf.all.mc_forwarding = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.forwarding = 1
net.ipv4.conf.default.mc_forwarding = 0
net.ipv4.conf.lo.forwarding = 1
net.ipv4.conf.lo.mc_forwarding = 0
net.ipv4.conf.venet0.forwarding = 1
net.ipv4.conf.venet0.mc_forwarding = 0
net.ipv4.conf.tun0.forwarding = 1
net.ipv4.conf.tun0.mc_forwarding = 0
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding = 1
net.ipv6.conf.all.mc_forwarding = 0
net.ipv6.conf.default.forwarding = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.mc_forwarding = 0
net.ipv6.conf.lo.forwarding = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.mc_forwarding = 0
net.ipv6.conf.venet0.forwarding = 1
net.ipv6.conf.venet0.mc_forwarding = 0
net.ipv6.conf.tun0.forwarding = 1
net.ipv6.conf.tun0.mc_forwarding = 0
```

I would really appreciate if someone could lead me in the right direction.

Comment: Has your server got IPv6 Internet connectivity?

Comment: Right, i forgot to mention it. The server has IPv6 connectivity and I am able to ping and establish connections to the outside from it.

Comment: OK, so where is your global prefix? You set up OpenVPN with ULAs..

Comment: I thought this is the way how it is supposed to be? Maybe you can provide some documentation about this so i will get firther into it.